# Porting a C++ application with Lua scripts to android?

Tags: android, c++, .net, lua

I'm looking into porting an application called ygopro (source code [here](https://github.com/Fluorohydride/ygopro)) to Android. I was just wondering if anybody can help me out by telling me what would be the best way to go about doing this? I would prefer to not spend more than about 60 hours on it and I certainly don't have the time to go through and rebuild everything from scratch. The code is in C++ and there are about 5,500 Lua scripts to do various things. Is there any easy way I can port this?

Comment: If you never ported anything before to Android. The windows project you linked to would be a steep climb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll note that the graphics library used by this project is based on [has been ported to android](http://gitorious.org/irrlichtandroid/pages/Home).

There are two demos available for that project. Those will show you how to write an android application that uses this library. I suggest you essentially hack your projects source into the framework they provide.

In terms of Lua, again you'll want to use an existing port. Many of the Lua ports are oriented towards allowing access to LUA from Java via JNI, but you just want a Lua shared library out of them to link to from your C++ code. You will probably want something like [AndroLua](https://github.com/mkottman/AndroLua) rather than the Android Scripting Environment. Pretty much, add all the folders in it's jni folder to your Android.mk includes, add it as a library, and you'll be good to go.

In terms of actual porting, I'm assuming that the project currently compiles happily under GCC. If that is the case, as you try to build it, it will complain about functions that are platform specific, and you will have to replace these. That should be manageable, if you are slowly adding code to the graphics framework demo as suggested. Beyond that, some libc functions are missing, but generally only rarely used ones.

Hope this helps. It goes without saying that you should complete some Android Native tutorials before starting. This project is more than a weekend.